# how to write a macro for recursive "slot-value" for defstruct?

Tags: struct, macros, lisp

**Problem**:  how to write a generic accessor macro for nested slot values for destructs (and for instances)?

**Motivation**: I am a LISP programmer envious of "dot notation" in Python etc where nested slot access is just a few dots away

**Use Case**: What i want to do is

```
(print (?? obj a b c) 
; i.e. ((print (slot-value (slot-value (slot-value obj 'a) 'b ) 'c))
(setf (?? obj a b c) newValue)
```

**Current results (which are ungood)**:  Best I could do is some nested defuns (see below). That approach has limitations:

- Those run a run time while, ideally, all the nested accessor work happens at load time.
- I had to write separate functions for `get` and `set` whereas if I could crack the `setf` macro expand problem, there'd only be the need for one `get`.

**My current code**: (and can anyone replace this with a single defmacro?)

```
(defun rslots-get (o l)
  (if (cdr l)
      (rslots-get (slot-value o (car l)) (cdr l))
      (slot-value o (car l))))

(defun rslots-set (o l z)
  (setf
   (slot-value o (car l))
   (if (cdr l)
       (rslots-set (slot-value o (car l)) (cdr l) z)
       z))
  o)

(defun rslots-push (o l z)
  (setf
   (slot-value o (car l))
   (if (cdr l)
       (rslots-push (slot-value o (car l)) (cdr l) z)
       (push z (slot-value o (car l)))))
  o)

(defmacro ?? (o   &rest l) `(rslots-get  ,o ',l   ))
(defmacro !! (o z &rest l) `(rslots-set  ,o ',l ,z))
(defmacro << (o z &rest l) `(rslots-push ,o ',l ,z))
```

ADVAthanxNCE!

Answer (score 2):

You can just write a simple macro that expands to the nested `SLOT-VALUE`s. A macro that expands into a place is a valid place itself, so you don't need to worry about the setf expansion.

```
(defmacro ?? (object &rest slots)
  (reduce (lambda (acc slot)
            `(slot-value ,acc ',slot))
          slots
          :initial-value object))

(macroexpand '(?? obj a b c))
;=> (SLOT-VALUE (SLOT-VALUE (SLOT-VALUE OBJ 'A) 'B) 'C)
```

You could also not quote the slot names in the macro to allow them to be calculated at run time.

```
(defmacro ?? (object &rest slots)
  (reduce (lambda (acc slot)
            `(slot-value ,acc ,slot))
          slots
          :initial-value object))

(macroexpand '(?? obj 'a 'b 'c))
;=> (SLOT-VALUE (SLOT-VALUE (SLOT-VALUE OBJ 'A) 'B) 'C)

(macroexpand '(?? obj 'a var 'b))
;=> (SLOT-VALUE (SLOT-VALUE (SLOT-VALUE OBJ 'A) VAR) 'B)
```

The previous assumes that you know the number of the slots. If you don't, then you will have to use a function.

```
(defun ? (object slot &rest more-slots)
  (reduce (lambda (obj slot)
            (slot-value obj slot))
          more-slots
          :initial-value (slot-value object slot)))

(defun (setf ?) (new-value object slot &rest more-slots)
  (loop :for (slot . tail) :on (cons slot more-slots)
        :with acc := object
        :if (null tail) ;SLOT is the last slot in the list.
          :return (setf (slot-value acc slot) new-value)
        :else
          :do (setf acc (slot-value acc slot))))

(defstruct zzzz z1 (z2 0) (z3))
(defstruct yyyy y1 y2 (y3 (make-zzzz)))
(defstruct xxxx x1 x2 (x3 (make-yyyy)))

(defvar *xxxx* (make-xxxx))

(? *xxxx* 'x3 'y3 'z2) ;=> 0
(incf (? *xxxx* 'x3 'y3 'z2))
(? *xxxx* 'x3 'y3 'z2) ;=> 1

(setf (apply #'? *xxxx* '(x3 y3 z2)) 100)
(? *xxxx* 'x3 'y3 'z2) ;=> 100
```

This approach is slightly inefficient, since modifying the place requires traversing the slots twice. You could use `DEFINE-SETF-EXPANDER` to write a more efficient setf expansion.

```
(defun ??? (object slots)
  (reduce (lambda (obj slot)
            (slot-value obj slot))
          slots
          :initial-value object))

(define-setf-expander ??? (object slots)
  (with-gensyms (slots-temp last-slot-temp obj target store) ;From Alexandria (or elsewhere).
    (values (list slots-temp
                  last-slot-temp
                  obj
                  target)
            `(,slots
              (first (last ,slots-temp))
              ,object
              (??? ,obj (butlast ,slots-temp)))
            (list store)
            `(setf (slot-value ,target ,last-slot-temp) ,store)
            `(slot-value ,target ,last-slot-temp))))

(let ((slots '(x3 y3 z2)))
  (setf (??? *xxxx* slots) 5)
  (incf (??? *xxxx* slots)))
;=> 6
```

This will store the object to be modified in a variable, so that modify macros won't need to look it up twice.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a recursive macro. The base case is a single argument, which simply translates into a call of `slot-value`. Otherwise it invokes itself recursively with just the additional slots.

```
(defmacro ?? (obj first-slot &rest more-slots)
  (if (null more-slots)
      `(slot-value ,obj ',first-slot)
      `(?? (slot-value ,obj ',first-slot) ,@more-slots)))
```

Comment: Exactly what the [`qref` macro](http://www.nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#N-013775DB)  in TXR Lisp [does (in the two simple slot cases)](http://www.kylheku.com/cgit/txr/tree/share/txr/stdlib/struct.tl?id=73890bf51805d416936b0d1e7ef87e6fe840010e#n207).

Comment: On reflection, I realized I needed to handle two cases. Case#1: the slots are known at load time-- and in that case, `??` is the perfect solution. Case#2 is when the slots are found at runtime. For this case I realized I only need one function (not the three others shown above). Specifically, I can replace all the above code with a function that passes an update lambda body  down to the slot  (where that code co-ordinates how to make the change).  To see that code, please browse https://gist.github.com/timm/4d0934758556cfdbc4511d07a3b6f5ef

Comment: @TimMenzies If you want to determine the slots at run time, you can just remove the quote from the macro, and instead quote constant slot names when using it.

Comment: Isn't slightly more that that? If you want to update the slots you have to wrap each recursive call in a setf (so the updated sub goes back to the parent)? See `change` in https://gist.github.com/timm/4d0934758556cfdbc4511d07a3b6f5ef.

Comment: You're only modifying the last slot. There's no need to set the others, since they don't change. That would only be a problem with immutable datastructures (in which case you could write a more complex setf expander with `DEFINE-SETF-EXPANDER`).

Comment: I adjusted as you said (see the new version of `change`). But one thing was a surprise. If I passed in a `push` as part of the function `f`, the nested struct was not modified. So now I do need a final setf at the leaf of the recursion... which means two calls to `slot-value ` at the leaf. Anyway to do it with just one?

Comment: @TimMenzies There's only one call to `SLOT-VALUE`. The first one is a call to `(SETF SLOT-VALUE)`, which is the setter function. There's no way around calling both if you want to both read and write the place. You could hide it behind a modify macro though (see `DEFINE-MODIFY-MACRO`, although you'll have to write a wrapper function around `FUNCALL` too, since it takes the arguments in wrong order). Personally I would just use a setf expander based approach instead of the `CHANGE` function (as you can see in my answer).

Comment: I think at this stage of my lisp newbie-ness, i will declare setf-expander a bridge too far. That said-- what a fascinating exercise. My code is now vastly shorter. And I now know much more about LISP and macros etc. Thanks`*(expt 10 6)` for your expert comments.